# Inserting logo into table

Tags: cv, resume

I am trying to insert a logo into the table under the duration part so that I will have a table where on the left there is the duration and lofo vertically, and on the other side there is the description and details. I tried many things but it didn't work. The description part shifts down all the time. Could you help?

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\\
\textsc{2020-Present} 
 & BlaBla University \\\textsc{}&\emph{Undergraduate Researcher}\\&\footnotesize{Numerical simulations are done on controlling reverberations through multi-layered soundproofing materials with acoustic metamaterial shaping. Experimental work is done on sound wave manipulation by using programmable phase array transducers. \\\textsc{}&\emph{Supervisor: Asst. Prof. Hasan Yılmaz}
}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The error in your current code is because you have "\\" within `{...}`, which is not allowed within the `tabular` environment

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making a new command for this definition so it is easier to keep formatting consistent across entries. I also recommend putting the position title (Researcher) before the institution (University). I think you want multirow not multicolumn for the logo. Hopefully I've read your mind...

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\newcommand{\education}[5]{%
  \textsc{#1}&\textbf{#2}\\ % date & position title
  \multirow{3}{2cm}{\\\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}&\emph{#3}\\ % logo & institution
  &\footnotesize#5\\ % details
  &\footnotesize\emph{#4}\\[\baselineskip]} % supervisor
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{9cm}}
    \education{2020--Present}{Undergraduate Researcher}{BlaBla University}{Supervisor: Asst. Prof. Hasan Yılmaz}
    {Numerical simulations are done on controlling reverberations through multi-layered soundproofing materials with acoustic metamaterial shaping. Experimental work is done on sound wave manipulation by using programmable phase array transducers.}
    \education{2020--Present}{Undergraduate Researcher}{BlaBla University}{Supervisor: Asst. Prof. Hasan Yılmaz}
    {Numerical simulations are done on controlling reverberations through multi-layered soundproofing materials with acoustic metamaterial shaping. Experimental work is done on sound wave manipulation by using programmable phase array transducers.}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

Comment: It will have the same logo with different universities.